# What is the cost of file organizations: heap file, sorted file, unclustered hash index on a delete operation using equality condition on a key?

Tags: sql-server, file-organization

I am learning database right now. Knows nothing basically about SQL server. :-p

I just see this question but I don't know how to answer it.

> Consider a delete operation specified using an equality condition on a key. Assuming that no record qualifies, what is the cost for the three file organizations: heap file, sorted file, unclustered hash index?

Anyone could answer this question? Thank you so much :-)

Comment: I think your teacher wanted you to google it and read about related things it and learn many other things while trying to answer this question. Stackoverflow really isnt the place for help with your homework.

Comment: ....there's no teacher....it's just the question I found online... don't make comment if you don't even want to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2014 (you tagged it with SQL Server and there were no NC hash indexes in SQL Server before), the answer is that IO cost for heap table is reading all pages that constitute the table, with clustered index (sorted file) it depends on depth of the B tree structure, and the unclustered hash index is a lookup into the hash table. All of these should include one or more reads on metadata pages (IAM and such).